# Javascript - post form won't submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having trouble with a post form in javascript. Here is my code...

```
    function save() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', '/quiz_score');

    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'Score');
    i.setAttribute('value', ""+score);
    form.appendChild(i);
    form.submit();
}
```

Can you see anything wrong with this code? I have a button setup to run this function onClick()...

```
<input type="button" name="finish" class="finished_button" onclick="save()"/>
```

Again, can anyone see any problems with this? When the button is clicked nothing happens. It appears it doesn't post and doesn't redirect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Press F12 in your browser to see the javascript Console. There's an error: `score is not defined`.

Comment: it doesn't know what `score` is! change it to `i.setAttribute('value', "1");` and it will work...then you can figure out how to get `score`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion score is just an integer stored as a variable elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Looking at the console I can now see I have this... TypeError: document.form is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the form to the body of the document by using `document.body.appendChild(form);`

```
function save() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', '/quiz_score');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'Score');
    i.setAttribute('value', ""+score);
    form.appendChild(i);
    form.submit();
}
```